# Building AOSP 5.1.51 with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04, android-source

Im trying to build AOSP 5.1.51, [I machine meets requirements](http://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) 
 Following the [instructions](http://source.android.com/source/building.html) but the make -j4 never build succesfully.
Recently trying to `lunch aosp_mips-eng` terminates with

```
target  C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/mips/lithium-mips.cc
In file included from external/chromium_org/v8/src/mips/lithium-codegen-mips.h:11:0, from external/chromium_org/v8/src/mips/lithium-codegen-mips.cc:36:
 external/chromium_org/v8/src/mips/lithium-mips.h: In member function 'bool v8::internal::LCodeGen::GeneratePrologue()':
 external/chromium_org/v8/src/mips/lithium-mips.h:2718:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
 class LChunkBuilder FINAL : public LChunkBuilderBase {
   ^
 Please submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropriate.
 See <http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html> for instructions.

 make: *** [/home/userAndroid/Builds/AOSP/target/product/generic_mips/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_gyp_intermediates/v8/src/mips/lithium-codegen-mips.o] Error 1
 make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

 #### make failed to build some targets (21:29 (mm:ss)) ####
```

And it ends there :(

Comment: how much RAM does your system have? Some steps in AOSP build eat RAM in huge chunks, and chromium module is one of them (probably biggest). Try to run make -j1. Does it build OK for ARM arch, is the issue MIPS-specific? You may try to re-install build tools, such as GCC, or change its version.

Comment: Hi Mixas, I'm experiencing same issue while building android 5.1.1 for bacon (oneplus one). I've only 2GB of RAM on my building system, but I added 20GB of SWAP memory which is located on a USB hard drive (through USB 2.0, I don't have 3.0 controller on my motherboard).

Comment: Another thing I want to notice, I can't get the error two times building the same file, but I always get an error telling me that an "Internal compiler error" occurred, and I got seg fault, then make wait for others jobs to end, then I got same message as OP (make failed to build...). The time the error occurs seems more or less random I guess. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Mixaz I have 8 Gp of RAM

Comment: @Ianis I do not know, I myself suffered from random errors in AOSP build like this one: https://plus.google.com/+hashcode0f/posts/URHo3hBmfHY I would recommend to set the build environment exactly the same as stated in AOSP docs, probably in a VM instance. After you get a stable build, you can try to move to your desktop environment. I found that AOSP builds do depend a lot on environment, and often fail with system updates. From my experience, having a dedicated VM instance for ROM builds is almost mandatory, unless you do not upgrade your system.

Comment: @Ianis on weak PC where using VM is not a good solution, you can consider using standalone linux installation via boot menu or `chroot`(this is for advanced users). 20 GB of swap is too much, I think 5 GB should be enough.

Comment: @goms, at the link you mentioned: "If you are running Linux in a virtual machine, you need at least 16GB of RAM/swap" so 8 GB may be not enough. Though I build CyanogenMod 5.0 on 6GB RAM + 4GB swap

Comment: @Mixaz I am not running on the virtual machine, I will try to remake it with 1 thread again after doing a fresh repo sync and see, probably this time will give me more info on error if any..

Comment: stuff ended here `make: *** [/home/frank/Android/Builds/source/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/third_party_webrtc_system_wrappers_source_system_wrappers_gyp_intermediates/third_party_webrtc_system_wrappers_source_system_wrappers_gyp.a] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (08:50:17 (hh:mm:ss)) ####`

Comment: @goms : Hi, did you finally succeed in building android?

Comment: @IanisRieuf No, not really! Will keep on debugging it. I wonder if I am the only one experiencing this issue on ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many tries, I ended up removing the entire source repo, fetch everything and build. Now everything works way better than before. I have not read everything to see if its the introduction of `jack`or things are better with the latest branch of android source.

If you are struggling with your build, this could be the way to go.